# How to select and drag the top item when overlapped

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two sprites in the world space. Both have box colliders. They are both set to the default sorting layer.
I made a drag n drop script attached to them.
They are int the same size and they are on each other, they have the same z index(0). When I drag the top one (I draw a line renderer around its bounds as it is selected) and I set another sorting layer (which is on the top) for which is dragged.
The problem is when I try to drag the top one only the bottom item moves.

How could I select the top object and drag it?

Comment: Would you mind attaching the drag and drop script you mentioned? It would be hard to do anything without knowing how the script works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046862/what-is-wrong-with-my-selection-raycast-code?rq=1

Does this question address your issue?

Comment: Is this theoretically possible to solve? Because I read somewhere that could happen that which item is selected is randomly, or maybe this information was bad. What do you think?

Comment: @AbhilashK I will check it, could happen that it is something to do with Raycasts. Thx.